# Enable HTML Button after certain delay

Tags: javascript

How do I display a countdown in a button, when the countdown gets to 0, it enables the button. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how to run code with a delay? How to enable a button?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Have you tried anything at all?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `setInterval` to execute a function periodically (every 1'000 ms). In the function that you pass to setInterval, you decrement the counter. You check if you have reached 0, and if so, you enable the button (and clear the interval).

Answer (score 0):

Use [.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for the countdown.

[Remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) the [HTML disabled Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_disabled.asp) at the end of the countdown.